# Select the name of the month in a different language using a simple Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How do I select the name of the month in a different language using a simple Oracle query?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( myDateCol, 'month' ) AS "Mes calendaristico" 
FROM MyTable;
```

The code above will return the exactly what I need but in English.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT TO_NCHAR( myDateCol, NA, NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE 'spanish' ) AS "Mes calendaristico" 
FROM MyTable;
```

but it does does not work, returning me the error:

> Error Code : 907
>   Error Message : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   Position : 50

Comment: Error Code : 907
Error Message : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
Position : 50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This documentation on `TO_NCHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2116.htm#OLADM694) suggests the syntax you tried, but it's for OLAP DML, not SQL. Because of that, the given example doesn't work.

The correct way would be to specify the NLS options as a string:

```
select 
  TO_NCHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=spanish') -- OCT
from dual
```

[TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) can do this too.

```
select
  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=spanish') , -- OCTUBRE   
  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=spanish') , -- Octubre   
  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=spanish') , -- octubre   
  TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=spanish') -- oct
from dual
```

Comment: Your first link is **not** the manual for Oracle's SQL functions, but for "OLAP DML Reference", so it's no wonder the syntax does not apply. The correct link for the `to_nchar()` function is: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions208.htm#SQLRF06137

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wow, I completely overlooked that. Thanks!